# How to generate a Bézier curve using 4 points（arbitrary), without using the built-in function of Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, splines

How to generate a Bézier  curve using 4 points（arbitrary), without using the built-in function of Mathematica?

The main point is that we do not use the built-in function in Mathematica, instead use a step-by-step program to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

Using cubic Bernstein polynomials, the Bézier curve of the points `{p1, p2, p3, p4}` is:

```
{(1 - u)^3, 3 u (1 - u)^2, 3 u^2 (1 - u), u^3}.{p1, p2, p3, p4} (* 0 < u < 1*)
```

Answer (score 4):

The Bernstein polynomials mentioned by Ulrich are in fact built-in as `BernsteinBasis[]`.

For instance:

```
PiecewiseExpand[BernsteinBasis[3, Range[0, 3], u], 0 < u < 1]
   {(1 - u)^3, 3 (1 - u)^2 u, 3 (1 - u) u^2, u^3}
```

---

Here is a short demo showing the equivalence of using `BezierCurve[]` directly with a construction using `BernsteinBasis[]`:

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}}}, 
              LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
                          Dynamic[With[{d = Length[pts] - 1}, 
                                       ParametricPlot[BernsteinBasis[d, Range[0, d], t].pts,
                                                      {t, 0, 1}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
                                                      Prolog -> {ColorData[97, 2],
                                                                 AbsoluteThickness[4], 
                                                                 BezierCurve[pts,
                                                                             SplineDegree -> d]},
                                                      PlotRange -> 4]]], LocatorAutoCreate -> True]]
```

[image: Bézier demo]

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click to add control points for the Bézier curve.